# chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen port, and request can't through a firewall in windows7

Tags: sockets, google-chrome-app

when window firewall is open, and tcpServer can't listen the request from remote machine.
and close the windows firewall,then tcpServer can listen the request。but sometimes we can't close the windows firewall, so any one face this problem before， is any automation way or settings can allow the remote request though the firewall。
This is some example code.

```
chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create({}, function(createInfo) {
    listenAndAccept(createInfo.socketId);
});

function listenAndAccept(socketId) {
  chrome.sockets.tcp.listen(socketId,
IP, PORT, function(resultCode) {
  onListenCallback(socketId, resultCode)
  });
}


var serverSocketId;
function onListenCallback(socketId, resultCode) {
  if (resultCode < 0) {
    console.log("无法监听连接：" +
  chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    return;
 }
  serverSocketId = socketId;
  chrome.sockets.tcpServer.onAccept.addListener(onAccept)
}
```

Comment: Nothing a browser can do, this is handled by the OS entirely.

Comment: Is any way bypass OS firewall?

Comment: Read earlier comment. The answer is no.